# PKPass Remove pass from wallet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wallet

I am working on wallet and pass is being made from server side. I want to remove the pass if existing in the wallet with same credentials. I had used the method `- (void)removePass:(PKPass *)pass;` but the pass is not removed from the wallet. Can anyone tell me the correct way to remove the pass.

Comment: Are you sure you are providing an equivalent pass (with the same serial-number and passTypeIdentifier)?? Otherwise, you can get all the passes in the wallet that your app has access to and loop over them and remove the one you want or use it to debug.

Comment: Yes everything which is provided is equivalent to pass.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69317684/pkpasslibrary-not-removing-pass