# PKPassLibrary not removing pass

Tags: ios, swift, ios-provisioning, passbook, apple-wallet

I am implementing apple in-app provisioning and I am able to add a credit card to apple wallet via my app for iPhone and Watch.
and I am able to get all these passes and work with them ... but when I want to delete one of them nothing happened

this is how I playing with deleting

```
... 
 let passLib = PKPassLibrary.init();

   let passesTest = passLib.passes();
   let passToRemove = passesTest[0];
   passLib.removePass(passToRemove)
...
```

`passLib.passes();` return all passes that I have in the wallet and are relevant to my app I select one and try to remove it ... but nothing happened. The pass is still there also the card is still in the wallet

any advice?

**UPDATE**

I should have `entitlements` right because I am able to add card to wallet this is a list of entitlements:
[image]

this is logic that I want to implement ... it is a React-Native module:

```
      @objc
  func removePass(_ data: NSDictionary, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
        
    let passTypeIdentifier = data["passTypeIdentifier"] as! String
    let serialNumber = data["serialNumber"] as! String

    
   let passToRemove = passLib.pass(withPassTypeIdentifier: 
   passTypeIdentifier, serialNumber: serialNumber)



      passLib.removePass(passToRemove)
      resolve(true)

  }
```

and the passes what I get from `passLib.passes();` looks like this

`<PKPaymentPass: 0x10611eba0>`

(to be readable I had to stringify it)

```
[ { localizedName: 'Pass',
    serialNumber: 'nc.prod.cert_efdeb2c6048c468ba6a941a063ce4345',
    passURL: 'shoebox://card/Nc4q8dwnXB1CGYG-YQRH4bIdhO4=',
    deviceName: 'iPhone',
    passType: 1,
    organizationName: 'Name Bank',
    localizedDescription: 'Name Mastercard Gold',
    isRemotePass: false,
    relevantDate: null,
    authenticationToken: null,
    webServiceURL: null,
    passTypeIdentifier: 'paymentpass.com.apple' } ]
```

**UPDATE**
I also try to remove this card from the Testflight version and it doesn't work... remove function return nothing

Comment: It's a very naive start, but are the entitlements in your Xcode project configured correctly? I assume yes since you were able to add a pass... Maybe you should try writing a piece of code outside of your business logic. This code would add a new pass and try to remove it immediately. Maybe this will help you figure out the problem...

Comment: I just add more info info my questions